# Disable ReSharper's rename usages in comments and string literals

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

I'd like to disable ReSharpers renaming feature for comments and string literals. Do you know how to do it? I wasn't able to find any *checkbox* for this feature.

[image]

I don't know anymore how many times I broke my projects by quickly pressing `Enter` and forgetting to uncheck it when I was renaming `name` parameter of some methods. It instantly breaks all `app.config`s any any other file using this string. This feature is dangerous so I'd rater use it as an **opt-in** feature than **opt-out**.

Answer (score 0):

If you uncheck that tick box, it should be persistent, and remain unchecked the next time you try to rename something.